# Struggling to find a solution to this improper integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am working on a probability exercice and I am trying to calculate E(Y) which comes down to this expression :

$$ E(Y) = \int_{-∞}^{+∞} y\frac{e^{-y}}{(1+e^{-y})^{2}} \, \mathrm{d}y $$

I tried to use integrals by part but it diverges and I can't find a good change of variables.

**Any idea ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This density is an even function, and the first moment integrand is an odd function. The expected value is then zero.

If we denote $f(y)=\dfrac{e^{-y}}{(1+e^{-y})^2}$, you can see that
$$
f(-y)=\frac{e^y}{(1+e^y)^2} = \frac{e^{2y} \cdot e^{-y}}{e^{2y}(e^{-y}+1)} = f(y)
$$

and if you interpret the improper integral as
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} y f(y) dy = \lim_{a \to +\infty} \int_{-a}^a y f(y) dy
$$

you see that its value must be zero.

Comment: Oh that's great. One more thing if I may : I have never seen the word integrand. What's the relation with the integral ?

Comment: @MachineLearner75 The integrand is the object being integrated.

Comment: Is there a similarity where if the integrand is even, then I can expect a known value or not at all ?

Comment: @MachineLearner75 If the integrand is even and the integral converges, there is no major simplification, You can just says things like
$$
E[y^2] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} y^2 f(t) dy = 2 \int_0^{+\infty} y^2 f(y) dy = 2 \cdot \frac{\pi^2}{6} = \frac{\pi^2}{3}
$$

but there is no actual simplification in the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the integrand is an odd function$\big(f(y)=-f(-y)\big)$ $\to$which means that integral is $0$

Answer (score 0):

$$E=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y\frac{e^{-y}}{(1+e^{y})^2}dy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{y}{4} \text{sech}^2(y/2) dy=0.$$
As the integrand is an odd function.

However,  $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{y}{4} \text{sech}^2(y/2) dy$$
is convergent and finite.